# numpy equivalents of eig() and eigs() functions of Matlab

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy

What is the numpy or scipy equivalent of

```
[V, D]= eig(A,-B)
```

And

`[V, D]= eigs(A,-B, 60, ‘SM')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`scipy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html) and [`scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html).

```
import scipy.linalg as la
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sla

# Matlab: [V, D] = eig(A, -B)
D, V = la.eig(A, -B)

# Matlab: [V, D]= eigs(A, -B, 60, ‘SM')
D, V = sla.eigs(A, 60, -B, which='SM')
```

Note that you will not, in general, get exactly the same results.  The eigenvalues might be in a different order, and the eigenvectors might have a different scaling (eigenvectors are not unique).

Comment: So, to try I have used ones(3, 3) * 3 for A, and ones(3, 3) * 5 for B. Using Matlab; `D = [-0.6 ; -0.485446217248779 ;-1.21030705211835e-17]`. And using Python Scipy : `[-6.00000000e-01+0.j,  3.51562903e-01+0.j, -1.41560356e-17+0.j]`. So the first eigenvalue is the same, but second one is a bit different. I can see the third one is basically zero. How can those two eigenvalues are the same?

Comment: Hmmm... with scipy 1.1 installed with Anaconda, I get the result that you got.  With the development version of scipy (`scipy.__version__` is `'1.2.0.dev0+3385e00'`), the scipy result agrees with Matlab.  I'll investigate further (but not right away).  In the meantime, can you do the same comparison, but with matrices that aren't quite so degenerate?  Both your `A` and `B` have rank 1.

Comment: Thanks. I am also using anaconda. To get the developer version should I just upgrade through pip ?

Comment: I have tried with another matrices which is 119, 119 as dimensions, but the `sla` part gives error as : `in eigs symmetric=False, tol=tol) File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 1069, in get_OPinv_matvec return LuInv(A - sigma * M).matvec
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32')`. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is: [`numpy.linalg.eig()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) and [`numpy.linalg.eigh()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html), but there are also `scipy` counterparts [`scipy.linalg.eig()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html) and [`scipy.linalg.eigh()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eigh.html) which may be compiled offer slightly different behavior and performances.