# Trying to convert Matlab to python: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Example_of_the_operator_on_a_grid)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I'm trying to get my head around the [example code on the wikipedia page for Laplacian matricies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Example_of_the_operator_on_a_grid).

It is written in MatLab and I only have access to open source tools.

I think most of it is fairly straight forward but I'm having a bit of trouble on this one line.

```
C0V = V'*C0; % Transform the initial condition into the coordinate system
% of the eigenvectors
```

Now my maths isn't up to scratch to really understand what the comment means. Judging by the matlab website this appears to be a [transposed matrix](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html) multiplied [(inner product)](https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html) by another matrix.
Where the left matrix (after transposing) is ( *m* x *p* ) and the right is ( *p* x *n* ).

The matrix `V` is produced by a call to [`eig`](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html) a few lines above, which from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248586/2727632) I am substituting [`scipy.linalg.eig`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html).

The problem is that C0 is clearly defined as an `N` x `N` matrix (ndarray), but in my code `V` is an `N**2` x `N**2` matrix. I have no way of knowing what shape `V` is in the original code.

For reference the wikipedia code is below, and below that is my attempt to rewrite it in python (using scipy and numpy), followed by the error attributed to the line described above.

### [Matlab code from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Example_of_the_operator_on_a_grid)

```
N = 20; % The number of pixels along a dimension of the image
A = zeros(N, N); % The image
Adj = zeros(N * N, N * N); % The adjacency matrix

% Use 8 neighbors, and fill in the adjacency matrix
dx = [- 1, 0, 1, - 1, 1, - 1, 0, 1];
dy = [- 1, - 1, - 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1];
for x = 1:N
    for y = 1:N
        index = (x - 1) * N + y;
        for ne = 1:length(dx)
            newx = x + dx(ne);
            newy = y + dy(ne);
            if newx > 0 && newx <= N && newy > 0 && newy <= N
                index2 = (newx - 1) * N + newy;
                Adj(index, index2) = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end

% BELOW IS THE KEY CODE THAT COMPUTES THE SOLUTION TO THE DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION
Deg = diag(sum(Adj, 2)); % Compute the degree matrix
L = Deg - Adj; % Compute the laplacian matrix in terms of the degree and adjacency matrices
[V, D] = eig(L); % Compute the eigenvalues/vectors of the laplacian matrix
D = diag(D);

% Initial condition (place a few large positive values around and
% make everything else zero)
C0 = zeros(N, N);
C0(2:5, 2:5) = 5;
C0(10:15, 10:15) = 10;
C0(2:5, 8:13) = 7;
C0 = C0(:);

C0V = V'*C0; % Transform the initial condition into the coordinate system
% of the eigenvectors
for t = 0:0.05:5
    % Loop through times and decay each initial component
    Phi = C0V .* exp(- D * t); % Exponential decay for each component
    Phi = V * Phi; % Transform from eigenvector coordinate system to original coordinate system
    Phi = reshape(Phi, N, N);
    % Display the results and write to GIF file
    imagesc(Phi);
    caxis([0, 10]);
     title(sprintf('Diffusion t = %3f', t));
    frame = getframe(1);
    im = frame2im(frame);
    [imind, cm] = rgb2ind(im, 256);
    if t == 0
        imwrite(imind, cm, 'out.gif', 'gif', 'Loopcount', inf, 'DelayTime', 0.1);
    else
        imwrite(imind, cm, 'out.gif', 'gif', 'WriteMode', 'append', 'DelayTime', 0.1);
    end
end
```

### My attempted translation

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy.linalg as la


N = 20 # The number of pixels along a dimension of the image
A = np.zeros((N, N)) # The image
Adj = np.zeros((N**2, N**2)) # The adjacency matrix

# Use 8 neighbors, and fill in the adjacency matrix
dx = [- 1, 0, 1, - 1, 1, - 1, 0, 1]
dy = [- 1, - 1, - 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
for x in range(N):
    for y in range(N):
        index = x * N + y
        for ne in range(len(dx)):
            newx = x + dx[ne]
            newy = y + dy[ne]
            if (newx >= 0 and newx < N 
                and newy >= 0 and newy < N):
                index2 = newx * N + newy;
                Adj[index, index2] = 1


# BELOW IS THE KEY CODE THAT COMPUTES THE SOLUTION TO THE DIFFERENTIAL EQUATION
Deg = np.diag(np.sum(Adj, 1)) # Compute the degree matrix
L = Deg - Adj # Compute the laplacian matrix in terms of the degree and adjacency matrices
D, V = la.eig(L) # Compute the eigenvalues/vectors of the laplacian matrix
D = np.diag(D)


# Initial condition (place a few large positive values around and
# make everything else zero)
C0 = np.zeros((N, N))
C0[1:4, 1:4] = 5
C0[9:14, 9:14] = 10
C0[1:5, 7:12] = 7

#C0 = C0(:) #This doesn't seem to do anything?


# matlab:C0V = V'*C0; % Transform the initial condition into the coordinate system
# of the eigenvectors

C0V = V.T * C0 # ???
```

### Error

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c3014dc90c9f> in <module>
      2 # of the eigenvectors
      3 
----> 4 C0V = V.T * C0

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (400,400) (20,20)
```

## Edit

It appears @hpaulj has identified my problem. The line I ommited is a `ravel` operation ie `C0 = C0(:)` takes a `20, 20` matrix to a `400, 1` vector. So I need

```py
C0 = C0.ravel()
```

Comment: Octave is open  source and quite close to MATLAB.

Comment: `*` in MATLAB is matrix multiplication.  `.*` is element wise.

Comment: With the shapes in the error, neither elementwise or matrix multiplication will work.  You'll need to work through the preceding code to track the evolution of shapes.   That kind of tracking is easier if you can run the MATLAB/Octave code as well.  Also, that kind of triple nest looping is acceptable in MATLAB since it does some degree of `jit` compilation, but, for performance sake, should be avoided in `numpy`.

Comment: I figured as much. I guess I am asking the wrong question. I really want to know why the projection on eignvalues works in this application. In the meantime I guess Octave is the best bet

Comment: `C0 = C0(:)` is `ravel`, so a (20,20) becomes (400,1) (or (1,400)).  That would allow it to interact with `eig` of a (400,400).